# base64 'payload' string from rabbitmq queue can't be decoded properly

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

```
from pyrabbit.api import Client
import base64

        msg = cl.get_messages('vhost', "somequeue", count=1)[0]
        rawinput = msg['payload']
        print rawinput
>> gAJ9cQEoVQdleHBpcmVzcQJOVQN1dGNxA4hVBGFyZ3NxBF1xBShY1AIAAHsiaGlzdG9y
        input = base64.b64decode(rawinput)
        print input

>> �}q(UexpiresqNUutcq�Uargsq]q(X�
```

This returns a weird characters and otherwise does not yield an appropriate parseable python dict. I'm wonder if there's some method to properly decode the payload from the rabbitmq. The original content of the message in the queue is from celery. In fact the queue contains celery tasks being queued on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seem the data is serialized by pickle or something others.

you can try like this:

```
import cPickle as pickle
rawinput = msg['payload']
input = rawinput.decode("base64")
data = pickle.loads(input)
print data
```